# Send mail is not encoding HTML properly

Tags: sitecore-api

I am trying to send mail in Sitecore using `Sitecore.MainUtil.SendMail(message)`. I have made `message.IsBodyHtml = true`. I debugged the code and found that in the body of message the string is encoded `(e.g: &lt;p&gt;Hi,&lt;/p&gt;)`. When the mail comes in outlook, its coming with HTML tags `(e.g: <p>Hi,</p>)`. How to get the mail without HTML Tags in it?.
(The whole purpose of the story is to send mail to user when the sitecore password expires.)

**Note:** I am using RTE to get the value for message from sitecore.

**Details of Environment.**

Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 151207).

.NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000

---

**EDIT**

Code copied from comment:

```
string mailBody = settingsItem.Fields[Constants.PasswordExpiryFieldNames.MailB‌​ody].Value.ToString(‌​);
var emailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, mailBody);
emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true; 
Sitecore.MainUtil.SendMail(emailMessage);
```

Comment: And when you switch to "HTML designer" mode in RTE, do you see &gt; and other encoded bits?

Comment: Can you share the code where you construct the message, please. What you are doing is correct, so it must be how you extract the message contents and put them in the message body.

Comment: In HTML designer mode I am able to see html tags and not the encoded bits

Comment: @MarkCassidy PFB the code.
For getting the string from RTE : `string mailBody = settingsItem.Fields[Constants.PasswordExpiryFieldNames.MailBody].Value.ToString();` 

For sending mail:
`var emailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, mailBody);
 emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
 Sitecore.MainUtil.SendMail(emailMessage);`

Comment: And if you put a breakpoint in your code and see what's the value of `mailBody` - is it encoded already?

Comment: @MarekMusielak yeah its already encoded. instead of tags its showing encoded values.

Comment: Use `string mailBody = Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render(settingsItem, Constants.PasswordExpiryFieldNames.MailB‌​ody)` and if it's still encoded, it means that what you typed in RTE is encoded. If so, go the RTE and switch to HTML design view and paste your message there.

Comment: For some reason your HTML is encoded. If FieldRenderer from comment above doesn't help(it is preferable to use it), you can try to decode your value `string mailBody = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(settingsItem.Fields[Constants.PasswordExpiryFieldNames.MailB‌​ody].Value.ToString(‌​));`

Comment: @MarekMusielak thanks for you help. Its working with `FieldRenderer.Render`. Kindly put this as answer with details so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Anton Thanks for the help. The issue got fixed with `FieldRenderer.Render` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `richtextField.Value` for obtaining content of a rich text field. Sitecore does a lot of processing (e.g. for link processing, media link protection, etc) in `renderField` pipeline.

You can execute `renderField` pipeline from code by using

> **Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render**

method. You need to pass the item and name of the field.

In your case the code will be:

```
string mailBody = FieldRenderer.Render(settingsIte‌​m, Constants.PasswordExpiryFieldNames.MailB‌​ody)
```